# Why I can't load dataset from seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, seaborn, data-science

I am trying to load the dataset iris from seaborn in my spyder
My code was simple:

```
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
print(df)
```

I am not getting output. I have tried in Jupiter notebook also, not getting any output

What to do?

I tried to load a dataset form seaborn named: 'iris' and also 'flights' but I can't.

Comment: Do you see an error message? Or do you get a complete empty output? Does outputting just a string work?

Comment: Try printing sns.get_dataset_names() to confirm connection is working.

Comment: There’s another question from yesterday with the same issue. What type of system? Linux Mac Windows. What version, etc? If you don’t mind telling us, what’s your geographic location?

Comment: Mine is a windows 11. Dell inspiron 3511                                                                                     I am getting an error message in sypder like                                                                                                                                          '''<urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>'''

Comment: What happens if you try in Google colab?

Comment: In jupyter notebook am getting no output

Comment: What if you try `df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/raw/titanic.csv')`?

Answer (score 0):

In the jupyter notebook, please check what the cell type is? It needs to be "code" for the notebook to execute the content of the cell.

If your cell type happens to be "Raw NBConvert", running it returns no output and no error either.

The cell type can be changed from the top menu bar as in the screenshot attached.

[image]